# What is the User class for?

Tags: spring-security

I've read information from 
[documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) but didn't understand when should I subclass this class or use it directly.

Also I don't understand when it's good practice to create my own UserDetails. Usually, I just create UserDetailsService and retrieve UserDetails from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to add functionality to those two classes that isn't already there? If yes, that's when you need to create subclasses from them.

> Usually, I just create UserDetailsService and retrieve UserDetails from there.

To me this looks like you're answering the question yourself. You do not need to subclass.